# Why does the heat of peppers seem to manifest differently?

Tags: spicy-hot, pepper

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but I have noticed that the heat in peppers seems to "manifest differently" depending on the kind of pepper. Some linger longer, and some are shorter lived. Some, like ghost pepper, "sneak up" on you, and others, like habanero in my opinion, are immediately spicy without remorse. I know the heat in peppers is chemically the same, being caused by capsaicin, but is there some reason for this observation or am I perhaps losing my mind? Or maybe it's just on a per pepper basis?

Comment: How are the peppers prepared (if at all)? If raw, I could imagine some process to do with the rate at which the capsaicin gets out of the pepper, perhaps because of the thickness of the flesh or even cell walls.

Comment: There's something in the idea, for sure. I've long noticed that, for instance, an Indian curry will get hotter every mouthful, yet a Thai curry you kind of 'get used to' as you're eating it.

Comment: I'm mostly speaking about the raw pepper, but I have noticed things similar to what Tetsujin is talking about.

Comment: Once you get to a whole dish, you have to consider the fats (in which capsaicin is soluble) and emulsifiers (that affect your contact with the fats) as well as other hot spices that are tasted in other ways

Comment: Likely different Capsaicinoid ratios https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin#Capsaicinoids I'd not be surprised if there were a hundred of these things.